# Err in $A.getCallback()[Err during LWC component connect phase:[Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')]]Failing descriptor: ltng:outApp

Tags: components, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc, aura-framework

ERRORS

•This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in $A.getCallback() [Error during LWC component connect phase: [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')]] Failing descriptor: {ltng:outApp}
•No component definition for c:b2bBuildToPar in the client registry - for best performance add <aura:dependency resource="c:b2bBuildToPar"/> to your extension of c:b2b_BuildToParApp.
o The error that it’s throwing doesn’t make sense because the <aura:dependency resource="c:b2bBuildToPar"/> is inside of the b2b_BuildToParApp.

<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" description="b2b_BuildToParApp">

-->

-->

```
<aura:dependency resource="c:b2bBuildToPar"/>
```

</aura:application>

•SecureElement does not allow access to charset

I'm trying to debug an issue we are having on our storefront in B2B commerce. We have a build to par page that you can add and remove products from. We have a CSR flow that Allows a user to access a contacts storefront with their user credentials. Then we have a User Experience flow that allows users to imitate contacts user and access the storefront as if they were that user. User Experience works fine, but when using the CSR flow and adding or deleting products from the build to par list in that instance we are given an error with the above logs/warnings. I'm not familiar with LWC and could use help breaking down what these errors mean and hopefully Identifying the issue.